# Error recovering journal ubuntu 18.04 dual boot

Tags: 18.04

I have ubuntu 18.04 dual boot on my pc along with windows
I forced shutdown the pc a while ago and now I am trying to boot into ubuntu but boot process is stuck onthis screen and after a while it shutdowns and I can't get the boot process to complete
please help me I don't know maybe the system is corrupted what should I do?
I can't post an image of the error because I don't have reputation
but It shows black screen with 2 lines

recovering journal

clean....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it).  Review and research these possible culprits along with their solutions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Booting problems after automatic software update: TPM error and Recovering journal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1141492/booting-problems-after-automatic-software-update-tpm-error-and-recovering-journ)